# how to find the pair content using beautifulsoup in Python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to **scrape** a web page: http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=apple, I want to get the english sentence and the pair chineses translate demo sentence. Now I could find all english sentence and chinese sentence using this command:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parseDictWeb():
    print("parse....")
    url = "http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=apple"
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html_page = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    mydivs = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "e"})
```

now the problem is that I could not pair the english sentence with chinese sentence. I want to  get the pair sentence and make sure all sentence are paired successfully. If I get all english and all chinese and paired by the array id.

```
mydivseng = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "e"})
mydivszh = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": "c"})
// do some pair logic by the array id
```

when some chinese sencence is null, the pair will broken. Maybe paired to the wrong sentence. how to get the pair in one time and make it paired 100% successful? I want the output should look like this:

```
lst = [
   {'e': ..., 'c': ...},
   {'e': ..., 'c': ...}
]
```

Comment: I modified your code to be reproducible, check if I didn't make mistakes.

Comment: Do you have an example where the pairs are broken?

Comment: I did not facing right now, but I think this situation will facing in the furture.@Corralien

Comment: What is your expect output? a list of dict? `lst = [{'e': '...', 'c': '...'}, ...]`?

Comment: yes, that exactly what I want to get.@Corralien I think I could get the class e and find the next siblings but I did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parseDictWeb():
    print("parse....")
    url = "http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=apple"
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html_page = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

    # Select only English and Chinese rows
    mydivs = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['e', 'c']})
    
    lst = []
    idx = -1
    for row in divs:
        # initialize a new element of the list if english
        if 'e' in row.attrs['class']:
            lst.append({'eng': row.text})
            idx += 1
        # update existing element of the dict if chinese
        else:
            lst[idx].update({'zh': row.text})
            
    return lst
    
out = parseDictWeb()
```